# Photoelectric Effect and heavy recoiling particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, atomic-physics, photoelectric-effect

I found this statement in Eisberg and Resnick's book for Quantum Mechanics which says:

> **"Our photoelectric energy equation remains
> valid, the effect being possible only because there is a heavy recoiling particle in addition
> to an ejected electron."**

Does this statement mean when a photon hits a free electron $e^-$, the $e^-$ splits into a more fundamental particle? OR Does it mean to say, the photon itself recoils conserving energy?
Please Clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the extent to which the interaction may be modeled as a "collision" between "particles", a photon can scatter off an electron, but it cannot be absorbed by a free electron.

We call the scattering process "Thomson scattering" when the photon transfers little energy to the electron. It may, however transfer as much as twice its momentum, and scatter back toward the source. Thomson scattering involves low energy photons, with energy much less than the mass energy of an electron.

At higher energy, the photon can transfer appreciable energy to the electron. For historical reasons we draw a distinction here, and call the process "Compton scattering", although there is no firm physical distinction.

Neither of these processes absorbs the photon: for that you need an additional recoiling particle to carry the excess momentum, as your textbook says.

In an experiment, it can be difficult to distinguish a photoelectron from a Compton scattered electron. For x-ray astronomy from the International Space Station, part of the instrumental background in the photoelectric detectors in the MAXI and NICER instruments is due to gamma rays from the Compton backscatter radar that the Soyuz capsule uses to detect the ground as it lands.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this statement mean when a photon hits a free electron, the e- splits into a more fundamental particle?

No

> Does it mean to say, the photon itself recoils conserving energy?

No

> Our photoelectric energy equation remains valid, the effect being possible only because there is a heavy recoiling particle in addition to an ejected electron.

There should be some energy-momentum 4-vector calculation in that section. What it means is that you must have some ion/nucleus to absorb the mismatch in energy and momentum, so that then the Einstein energy-momentum relations and the conservation of energy and momentum will allow the photoelectric effect to happen.

Comment: Compton scattering?

Comment: @JohnDoty read the question properly. The context makes it clear it is not talking about that.

Comment: "the photon itself recoils conserving energy?" is asking about Compton scattering. Now *technically* that's not the "photoelectric effect", but those are just words. It's something that happens in real life, and we should acknowledge that.

Comment: It will be preferable if you would cease to comment on my posts. Compton scattering is also forbidden by relativistic energy-momentum conservation, and will be made possible by the same mechanism that I have written. That is what the book is asking, the OP is asking, what I have answered, and it is you who want to bring in word play.

Comment: What are you taking about? Compton scattering is not forbidden by energy-momentum conservation. Please read up on it: electron-photon scattering is an extremely important process in the universe.

Answer (score 0):

If a photon in the range of light strikes a free electron almost noting happens, if the Photon has higher energy, so xray photons you have Compton effect, read about it for example in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering

Comment: Well, if it has much less energy than the mass energy of an electron, you get Thomson scattering, which doesn't transfer much energy to the electron.